# How to render buttons inside flutter canvas?

Tags: flutter, dart, drawing

I'm working in a flutter draw project, and need to implement the feature of resize the last path. But when i change some item in the list, the listener broke! I don't know what i do wrong! My problematic code is:

```dart
    [...]
      Widget buildCurrentPath(BuildContext context) {
        ValueNotifier<DrawingFunction> activeFunction =
            ValueNotifier(DrawingFunction.draw);
    
        return Listener(
          onPointerDown: (details) {
            final box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
            final offset = box.globalToLocal(details.position);
    
            if (allSketches.value.isNotEmpty) {
              Rect scaleButtonPosition =
                  allSketches.value.last.getScaleButtonPosition();
    
              if (scaleButtonPosition.contains(offset)) {
                print("Scale button pressed");
                activeFunction.value = DrawingFunction.scale;
              }
            }
            if (activeFunction.value == DrawingFunction.draw) {
              currentSketch.value = Sketch.fromDrawingMode(
                Sketch(
                  points: [offset],
                  color: selectedColor.value,
                  size: strokeSize.value,
                ),
                drawingMode.value,
                filled.value,
              );
            }
          },
          onPointerMove: (details) {
            final box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
            final offset = box.globalToLocal(details.position);
    
            print(activeFunction);
    
            if (activeFunction.value == DrawingFunction.draw) {
              final points = List<Offset>.from(currentSketch.value?.points ?? [])
                ..add(offset);
    
              currentSketch.value = Sketch.fromDrawingMode(
                Sketch(
                    points: points,
                    color: selectedColor.value,
                    size: strokeSize.value),
                drawingMode.value,
                filled.value,
              );
            } else if (activeFunction.value == DrawingFunction.scale) {
              double scale = 0.9;
    
              Sketch sketch = allSketches.value.last;
              Path transformedPath = sketch.path
                  .transform(Matrix4.diagonal3Values(scale, scale, 1).storage);
    
              sketch.path = transformedPath;
              //currentSketch.value = sketch;
            }
          },
          onPointerUp: (details) {
            if (activeFunction.value == DrawingFunction.draw) {
              allSketches.value = List<Sketch>.from(allSketches.value)
                ..add(currentSketch.value!);
    
              currentSketch.value = null;
            }
          },
          child: RepaintBoundary(
    [...]
```

in this example, the update is commented: `//currentSketch.value = sketch;` and the drawingFuncions keep scale funcion when you click in the rendered button and move the pointer, but if i uncomment this line, the pointer down change the drawingFuncion to .scale but onPointerMove broke this and the drawingFuncion back to draw.

What i need to do? Same tips for Flutter canvas?

Answer (score -2):

***To render buttons inside a Flutter canvas, you'll need to use custom painting with the CustomPainter widget and handle button click events manually. Here's a basic example of how to render buttons on a Flutter canvas:***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Canvas Buttons Example'),
      ),
      body: CanvasButtonDemo(),
    ),
  ));
}

class CanvasButtonDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CanvasButtonDemoState createState() => _CanvasButtonDemoState();
}

class _CanvasButtonDemoState extends State<CanvasButtonDemo> {
  List<Button> buttons = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    buttons.add(Button(50, 50, 100, 50, 'Button 1', onPressed: () {
      print('Button 1 pressed');
    }));
    buttons.add(Button(50, 150, 100, 50, 'Button 2', onPressed: () {
      print('Button 2 pressed');
    }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      size: Size(double.infinity, double.infinity),
      painter: CanvasButtonPainter(buttons),
    );
  }
}

class Button {
  final double x;
  final double y;
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final String label;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  Button(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height, this.label, {required this.onPressed});
}

class CanvasButtonPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<Button> buttons;

  CanvasButtonPainter(this.buttons);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    for (var button in buttons) {
      final rect = Rect.fromPoints(Offset(button.x, button.y), Offset(button.x + button.width, button.y + button.height));
      canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);

      final textPainter = TextPainter(
        text: TextSpan(
          text: button.label,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
        ),
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      );

      textPainter.layout(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: button.width);
      textPainter.paint(canvas, Offset(button.x, button.y));

      // Add touch handling
      canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
      canvas.drawRect(rect, Paint()..color = Colors.transparent);
      final buttonRect = rect.shift(Offset(0, size.height));
      canvas.drawRect(buttonRect, Paint()..color = Colors.transparent);

      final touchArea = Rect.fromPoints(rect.topLeft, buttonRect.bottomRight);
      canvas.drawRRect(
          RRect.fromRectAndRadius(touchArea, Radius.circular(8.0)), Paint()..color = Colors.transparent);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

***This code defines a Button class to store button properties like position, size, label, and an onPressed callback. The CanvasButtonPainter class is used to paint the buttons on the canvas, and it also handles touch events to detect button presses.
This is a basic example, and you can customize it further as needed for your specific use case.***

Comment: Yes, i rendered my button , now my problem is other, i define a method in my class Sketch to use transforms, but i cant see the path updating in real time, the changes only appear on the end :(

Comment: Have a look at the `shouldRepaint` function at the bottom of the answer. You can compare `this` and `oldDelegate`, and if certain fields have changed (you can check `x`, `y` etc) you can return `true` so the button will redraw